# DYNAMIC-EXTENT ignored in CLISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, heap-memory, clisp, stack-memory

I read [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_dynami.htm) that "it is permissible for an implementation to ignore" the dynamic-extent declaration in Common Lisp, and I was wondering if it is in fact ignored in the CLISP implementation.

I have tried testing with the following code:

```
(let ((b (cons 1 2))) 
 (declare (dynamic-extent b)) 
 (list b))
```

Which returns:

```
((1 . 2))
```

My guess is that it is ignored, but I wanted to be sure.

Also, if it is ignored, is there a way for me to explicitly allocate memory to the stack rather than the heap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*> is there a way for me to explicitly allocate memory to the stack rather than the heap?*

No, and you can be thankful of it because it eliminates an entire category of bugs from the programs: there can be no "dangling pointers" to already dead objects that make your program crash.

Furthermore, with CLISP or similar implementations, you don't need stack-allocated memory because:

- The garbage collector eliminates short-lived objects quickly, and CLISP's garbage collector consumes usually less than 10% of the CPU time.
- CLISP's garbage collector is generational, which means that collecting short-lived object is particularly fast. And once a short-lived object has been collected, the next short-lived object will be allocated in the same small memory area - so you have a similar speed improvement (by use of locality) as with stacks.

Finally, insisting on stack allocation of objects prevents you from freely choosing the programming style that is adapted to your problem. Lisp supports many programming styles: functional, procedural, object-oriented, pattern-based, logic, relational, rule, goal-oriented, and more. By requesting stack allocation, you restrain yourself to functional and procedural programming style; this really does not bring you forward.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CLISP ignores the `dynamic-extent` declaration.
See [CLISP Implementation Notes](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/declarations.html), which do not mention it explicitly yet (the [beta version](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/beta/impnotes/declarations.html#decl-min) does).

If you want control over memory management (e.g., you enjoy debugging segfaults and memory leaks), you should be using C.

PS. An implementation that respects the `dynamic-extent` declaration would probably segfault on your code.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Do you know of any way to explicitly allocate memory in CLISP? I understand that CLISP has automatic memory management, but I want to know if there's a way to get around this.

Comment: @TatsuyaYokota: if you want to control memory management, use C.

Comment: While I agree that it is not often needed or desirable, there are other CL implementations which do support stack-allocation: if you are absolutely sure you *need* it (and not just gratuitously optimising something that does not need optimising) you could consider them.

Comment: @TatsuyaYokota: CFFI will allow you to allocate memory and interact with it but of course not for storing lisp objects. static-vectors is also handy in cases where you want an array at a fixed (potentially unmanaged) point in memory, however it only supports certain numeric types. Also clisp is not a great common lisp implementation, please consider sbcl, ccl (which compile to machine-code) or ecl (if compiling to c is a requirement)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a great question! (have ingratiate myself because my karma is so low!)

As others have mentioned CLISP ignores `declare` `dynamic-extent`. However other implementations do obey it, and for good reason. Quoting SBCL:

> SBCL has fairly extensive support for performing allocation on the
>   stack when a variable is declared `dynamic-extent`. The
>   `dynamic-extent` declarations are not verified, but are simply
>   trusted as long as `sb-ext:*stack-allocate-dynamic-extent*` is
>   true.

Also, keep in mind that CL declarations are promises made **by** the programmer **to** the lisp system. Declarations, in general, have no defined observable behavior either when the programmer keeps his promise or when they are broken.

The alway helpful and cheery SBCL documentation goes on to say:

> If dynamic extent constraints specified in the Common Lisp standard
>   are violated, the best that can happen is for the program to have
>   garbage in variables and return values; more commonly, the system will
>   crash.
>
> In particular, it is important to realize that dynamic extend is
>   contagious:

```
(let* ((a (list 1 2 3))
       (b (cons a a)))
   (declare (dynamic-extent b))
   ;; Unless A is accessed elsewhere as well, SBCL will consider
   ;; it to be otherwise inaccessible -- it can only be accessed
   ;; through B, after all -- and stack allocate it as well.
   ;;
   ;; Hence returning (CAR B) here is unsafe.
   ...)
```

The takeaway being: generally in lisp declarations don't result in the change of a conforming program's 'meaning'. All bets are off if your program runs counter to your declared intent.  What the 'effect' of a declaration is, i.e. **how** the compiler optimizes the resulting code (and whether it optimizes it at all) vary from implementation to implementation and even from version to version.